# Q: Existence of embedding of decomposition groups in Galois extension.

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a number field $K$, let $L$ and $M$ be two finite extensions and $M$ be normal over $K$.  This implies the composite field $LM$ is normal over $L$.  Then  $\mathrm{Gal}(LM/L)$ is embedded in $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ by restricting automorphisms to $M$. Let primes *V*, *Q*, *U*, and *P* be contained in *LM*, *L*, *M*, *K* respectively.

I have to show that there is also an embedding from the decomposition groups $D(V|Q)$ to $D(U|P)$.

I know that for any $\tau \in D(V|Q)$ there exists an inverse. If $\tau(U)\subset U$ then $\tau^{-1}(U)\subset U$ so taking $\tau$ of both sides of the second containment gets me $U\subset\tau(U)$ implying $\tau(U)=U$ so $\tau\in D(U|P)$. Thus an embedding exists (I think).

My problem is in showing why the first containment $\tau(U)\subset U$ is true.  It must be due to $\tau$ being in $D(V|Q)$ but I can't figure out why.

Comment: What is the relationship between $U$ and $V$?  If you know this, you'll have your answer.

Comment: *V* is a prime over *U*, so U$\subset$V implies $\tau$(U)$\subset\tau$(V) implies $\tau$(U)$\subset$V. But can I conclude $\tau$(U)$\subset$U from there?

Comment: More is true than just $U \subseteq V$.  What is the definition of what it means for $V$ to lie over $U$?

Comment: I don't have a great definition, but I see that five properties have to hold. If *S* is the ring of integers of *LM*, then $V|US$ and $US\subset V$ being two properties that interest me.  What would $\tau(S)$ look like?

Comment: Lying over means that $V \cap M = U$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau(V) = V$.  Since $M$ is Galois over $K$, $\tau(M) = M$.  Then

$$\tau(U) = \tau(V \cap M) = \tau(V) \cap \tau(M) = V \cap M = U$$

Comment: So $\tau(M)=M$ because $\tau$ is in $Gal(LM/L)$ and because there exists an embedding to $Gal(M/K)$ for all $\sigma \epsilon Gal(LM/L)$ when $\sigma$ is restricted to M $\sigma(M)=M$. Right?

Comment: Yes.  $\tau_M$ is a $K$-embedding of $M$, so it is automatically an automorphism of $M$ by normality.  This is why $\textrm{Gal}(LM/L) \rightarrow \textrm{Gal}(M/K), \sigma \mapsto \sigma|_M$ is a well defined function.